# ¿Cuáles son los mejores sitios para compartir enlaces y atraer tráfico?

Tags: discusión, beta

Una pregunta sencilla pero creo que a la vez necesaria para atraer tráfico: se ha hablado en otras ocasiones de compartir enlaces para dar visibilidad al sitio, pero ¿cuáles son los mejores sitios para hacerlo? ¿Tenemos identificados qué foros de español hay cuyos usuarios aún no nos conocen? Además de los foros, ¿hay cuentas de Facebook o Twitter que nos puedan ayudar a comunicar nuestras preguntas y respuestas? ¿Alguna otra alternativa? ¿Canales de IRC? ¿Grupos de mensajería en Telegram, WhatsApp o similares?

Comment: ¡Nótese que he mencionado [tu sugerencia](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2500/1674) de hace un tiempo en Meta! [Favicon of Earth Science and Spanish are too similar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285489/209901). ¡Edita lo que quieras!

Comment: @fedorqui y no sabes la ilusión que me hizo. :-) Veo que tu respuesta tiene ya algunos votos, aunque me temo que si queremos tener un icono propio tenemos que promocionar mucho más el sitio y salir de beta. Estoy empezando a sopesar el redactar mis preguntas en inglés...

Comment: Gracias a ti por currártelo ;) A ver en qué queda el tema, pues lleva muchos votos y eso en [meta.se] es buen síntoma para que los empleados le echen una ojeada. En número de visitas estamos genial, básicamente necesitamos más preguntas. La tendencia es buena pero sigue faltando... ¡A correr la voz se ha dicho!

Comment: Carlos, ¿te animas a crear un anuncio del sitio para proponerlo en [Anuncios de promoción de la comunidad - 2016](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/q/1185/83)?

Comment: @fedorqui pero eso es solo para anuncios de proyectos de programación open source, ¿no?

Comment: Lo pregunto. En algunas publicaciones he visto que estos anuncios se usan para anunciar otros sitios. A ver qué dicen...

Comment: Vale, me lié, se trata de los Community Promotion Ads, como por ejemplo [estos de ELL](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/2854/3462). Para estos sí podríamos plantear un cartel para este sitio.

Comment: @fedorqui chachi, pero habrá que buscar la versión de 2017, ya que dicen que resetean los anuncios todos los años...

Comment: Por lo que veo, suelen abrir la pregunta más o menos por estos días del año. Estaré atento a [lo que publica Grace Note](http://stackexchange.com/users/102159/grace-note?tab=activity)... :)

Comment: ¡[ha llegado el día](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2578/1674)!

Comment: Anda de hecho veo que hace tiempo ya preguntó esto Flimzy: [How can we promote our site?](http://meta.spanish.stackexchange.com/q/216/1674). Podemos mover la respuesta allí y la marcamos como duplicada.

Answer (score 2):

Listado de sitios, cuentas de redes sociales y demás que nos pueden ayudar a compartir enlaces, de forma que sean de utilidad para sus usuarios y nos puedan generar más tráfico:

- [Reddit.com](https://www.reddit.com/)
  Interesante tanto para atraer visitas como para aportar contenido que luego podemos poner en forma de respuestas.
  Existe un foro de [preguntas acerca del español en general](https://www.reddit.com/r/Spanish), otro específico para [aprender español](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnspanish), pero es recomendable encontrar el subforo pertinente si la pregunta es de tipo regional: para preguntas de Colombia, por ejemplo, usaremos el [subforo de Colombia](https://www.reddit.com/r/Colombia/).
- [meneame.net](https://www.meneame.net/)
  Dispone de varios subforos en los que publicar enlaces que apunten a preguntas o respuestas del sitio, como por ejemplo el [subforo de etimología](https://www.meneame.net/m/Etimologia).