# ¡Hagamos un póster para anunciarnos! / Let's have an Ad to promote the site!

Tags: discusión, promoción-de-la-comunidad

En [¿Cuáles son los mejores sitios para compartir enlaces y atraer tráfico?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2509/1674), Carlos Alejo preguntaba cuáles pueden ser los mejores lugares donde publicitar este sitio, Spanish Language.

Estuvimos comentando un poco y al cabo de unos meses recordé que existen los [Community Promotion Ads](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/): una serie de anuncios pequeñitos que los usuarios de cada comunidad escogen para que aparezcan en la parte derecha de la página.

El proceso de selección es anual y se da entre aquellos sitios que ya están [graduados](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/257614/209901). Como nosotros no lo estamos ([seguimos en beta](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/14456/spanish-language)) uno podría decir: "ooooh, qué pena, no podemos usar esta idea". Y es verdad, no podemos escoger qué anuncios veremos.

Ahora bien, lo que sí podemos hacer es utilizar los otros sitios para promocionarnos. Esto es práctica común ([un ejemplo](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3433/3462)) y ayuda a hermanar sitios, así como descubrirlos a los usuarios de cada uno.

Acabo de ver que el Community Manager [Grace Note](http://stackexchange.com/users/102159/grace-note) estuvo publicando al respecto en el Meta de muchos sitios graduados, por lo que he recopilado aquellos en los que creo que podríamos participar:

- [English Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) → [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3431/3462)
- [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com) → [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4293/6997)

En English Learners lo enfocaría como "¿cansado de aprender inglés? ¡el español mola más!" :)

En Travel lo podríamos plantear como "¿qué te parece aprender un poco de español antes de aventurarte en Hispanoamérica o España?".

Yo soy malo creando imágenes, por lo que ojalá que alguno tenga ideas y capacidad para crear alguna chula. Podría colgarla aquí como respuesta por si los demás quieren/queremos hacer alguna sugerencia.

La parte importante de las reglas la indico al final de esta publicación.

---

Let's have Community Promotion Ads to get traffic into Spanish Language! As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/05/community-promotion-ads/), this is a tool for the graduated sites to chose their own ads.

Since we are still in beta, we cannot opt to this. However, we can create ads ourselves into graduated sites so that we get visits from there.

These are the sites in which I do think we can get good feedback:

- [English Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) → [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3431/3462)
- [Travel](http://travel.stackexchange.com) → [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4293/6997)

> #### How does it work?
>
> The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following
>   rules, or they will be ignored.
>
> 1. All answers should be in the exact form of:
>
> ```
>     [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]
>
>        [1]: http://image-url
>        [2]: http://clickthrough-url
> ```
>
> Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
>
> #### Image requirements
>
> - The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
> - Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
> - Must be GIF or PNG
> - No animated GIFs
> - Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
> - If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.
>
> #### Score Threshold
>
> There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently
>   **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

Comment: En Stack Overflow mismamente vi un anuncio que era genial, era un sencillo anuncio del sitio Ask Different que solo ponía ese título ("Ask different") en el anuncio, nada más, y enlazaba a una pregunta de alguien que quería saber [si podía limpiar el teclado de su Macbook Pro con vodka](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/268046). Desde luego que es una pregunta diferente. :D Así que se me ocurría poner en el anuncio la pregunta del sitio que refleje la cuestión más característica del español, como alguna sobre _ser_ o _estar_, o similar, que la entienda cualquiera mínimamente iniciado.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Jaja podríamos preguntar cómo limpiarlo con _güisqui_ :) Pero de hecho es diferente, esos anuncios se crean automáticamente a partir de las preguntas del [Hot Network Questions](http://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot) y apuntan a la pregunta en sí, no al sitio. En alguna ocasión he visto alguno de nuestro sitio; no sé qué criterio usan pero siempre salen de esa lista que comento. Dicho lo cual, no sería mala idea captar la atención en base a una pregunta específica.

Comment: My attention was drawn to this site by the Hot Network Questions (I was a member of CrossValidated at the time). After a while I decided to join. I think the site does appear on HNQ fairly often considering how many active users it has.

Comment: @mdewey yes, the Hot Network Questions (HNQ) is a great entry point to the site and source of traffic. I noticed that a question that gets some votes and few comments appears into the HNQ quite straight forward and the bias in comparison with big sites is extremely helpful. What would you suggest as a good catchy sentence to get people like you, not native but interested in Spanish?

Answer (score 2):

[image: Difference between "chiste" and "chanza"]

Comment: Que conste que es solo un boceto. Problemas con los que me encuentro: no sé qué colores escoger para representar el idioma español. En principio pensé en el azul y el rojo, porque son colores que aparecen en todos los países de habla hispana (ya sea al menos uno, o los dos). Como la imagen que he cogido (que representa los sitios donde se habla español o hay una comunidad notable de hablantes) ya usa el rojo, he puesto el texto en azul. Se admiten sugerencias, ideas y críticas constructivas.

Comment: Qué rapidez :)) Estaba fijándome en [este ejemplo](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/a/3433/3462) y me pareció útil el hecho de llamar a la acción con un _visit_, _come on over_, etc. ¿Qué te parece?

Comment: @fedorqui se trata de tener una frase eslogan con gancho. En mi propuesta la parte de "Spanish is fun!" puede hacer esa acción de gancho, sobre todo teniendo en cuenta que los visitantes de English Learners tienen interés por los idiomas (en mayor o menor medida). Aún tengo que pensar una para Travel.

Comment: I think the colours for countries like Australia are going to confuse people. How about 100 manikins with colours for English speakers, Spanish spekers and other languages? I have absolutely no idea how to do that myself.

Comment: Are we trying to attract real beginners? If not then should it not say _español es muy divertido_ or similar?

Comment: @mdewey I'm not trying anything, just posted a tentative ad following a bit fedorqui's idea. I'd really like to see other ads, to more the better, so we can vote the best.

Comment: En [english.se] también tienen anuncios y veo que los de [latin.se] se animan a anunciarse allí --> [Explore the roots of English at the Latin Stack Exchange](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/10006/37429)

Comment: @fedorqui pues deberíamos buscar un anuncio con un mensaje positivo, más que uno que menosprecie el inglés. A ver cómo lo enfocamos, porque yo podré hacer un pequeño montaje, pero de ahí a ser publicista...

Comment: A ver si alguien más se anima a sugerir frases. Esperaba que con lo de _featured_ hubiera más debate.

Comment: Quizá llego un poco tender a esta fiesta, pero siguiendo la idea de @fedorqui propondría un slogan basado en el hecho de que el español es [el segundo idioma más hablado del mundo](https://www.babbel.com/en/magazine/the-10-most-spoken-languages-in-the-world). Me gusta especialmente del enlace "If you want a language that will open up whole continents to you, Spanish is your best bet" y le viene como anillo al dedo al boceto de Carlos que muestra los países donde se habla español.

Comment: SOes ha abierto [la publicación oficial para solicitar anuncios](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4713/83) y allí estaría muy bien que publicáramos. cc @Diego

Answer (score 1):

[image: "Chinga" - common slang? Origin?]

La siguiente opción la pongo solo si al público mexicano no le importa (aunque la imagen del sombrero tiene una licencia Creative Commons que nos obliga a citar al autor en caso de que se elija):

[image: "Chinga" - common slang? Origin?]

Por sugerencia de mdewey (personalmente me gusta cómo ha quedado, y la imagen de la pirámide es de dominio público, así que podemos usarla sin problema):

[image: "Chinga" - common slang? Origin?]

Y por si lo queréis ver con otros colores:

[image: "Chinga" - common slang? Origin?]

Comment: Un posible anuncio para el sitio Travel, aunque podría servir igualmente para el de English Learners.

Comment: ¡Qué bueno! El contraste rojo verde duele un poco a la vista, ¿se podría reducir un poco? También se me ocurre que podríamos poner un [sombrero mexicano](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/transformice/images/a/a4/Sombrero_Mejicano.png/revision/latest?cb=20120226121205&path-prefix=es) ladeado encima del logo del sitio... ¿o suena demasiado para _guiris_?

Comment: @fedorqui La idea del sombrero se me ocurrió a mí también, pero pensé que sería como ponerle un traje de flamenca y no me gusta nada que identifiquen España con un traje de flamenca, así que descarté la idea y dejé el logo. El contraste es por usar los colores exactos de la bandera mexicana, he intentado usar otros tonos pero queda aún peor. A mí no me parece que así duela tanto la vista, pero puedo probar otras opciones...

Comment: @fedorqui va, al final he puesto una opción con sombrero. La imagen que me has enlazado, ¿te has asegurado de que está libre de derechos de autor?

Comment: Andeleeee :) Pues no me he asegurado para nada, ni lo he mirado vaya. Lo siento. Viene de [Wikia](http://es.transformice.wikia.com/wiki/Archivo:Sombrero_Mejicano.png) y veo que tiene _Creative Commons Reconocimiento-Compartir_, por lo que habría que mencionarlos en algún sitio. Dado que es un palo, he buscado un poco y encontré [esta](https://pixabay.com/en/sombrero-mexican-hat-mexico-ethnic-26735/) de pixabay.com.

Comment: If you think the sombrero is stereotyping how about what Wikipedia calls a Mesoamerican pyramid? I di wonder about _frijoles refritos_ but they are not very photogenic.

Comment: @mdewey good idea, I like the result.

Comment: ¡Qué buena la de la pirámide! Me gusta especialmente la de fondo verde.

Comment: @fedorqui ¿no decías que te chirriaban los colores? :D ¿Cuánto tiempo tenemos para proponer el anuncio? Y por otro lado, no veo que otros sitios de Stack Exchange se anuncien en [Travel.SE], ¿seguro que nuestro anuncio es relevante allí?

Comment: @Carlos me sigue doliendo un poco a la vista, cierto xD Sin embargo, al haber más imagen de fondo se atenúa jeje. Yo creo que podemos probarlo: creo que encaja con [lo descrito allí de](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/q/4293/6997) _anything else your community would genuinely be interested in_. Si resulta que no se acoge bien, recibimos los votos negativos con dignidad y habremos aprendido la lección :) En cuanto al tiempo, no hay fecha límite. Sin embargo, dado que estas publicaciones están _featured_ ahora es cuando mayor visibilidad tendrán. Yo lo haría ya, vaya.

Comment: @fedorqui pues si tienes cuenta en Travel te cedo los honores, a mí la verde de la pirámide también es la que más me mola.

Comment: [Enviado](http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/a/4314/6997). A ver qué nos comentan. ¡Muchas gracias por el curro!

Comment: Pues a lo tonto ya llevamos dos votos, con cuatro más entraremos en la rueda.

Comment: I suggest: "Want to get some practice before etc."  (As it stands it looks fragmentary.) // ELU (English Language & Usage) and Linguistics would also be good. // The moderators and community here are especially friendly and supportive.  This little testimonial should appear somewhere, not sure where.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba de cargar la imagen con los bounties del sitio:

[image: Current Travel.SE bounties]
<sub>(fuente: [herokuapp.com](https://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/spanish.stackexchange.com/bounty.png))</sub>