# Y tú ¿por qué participas en Meta?

Tags: discusión, meta, usuarios, participación

Inspirado por [Y tú ¿por qué no participas en Meta?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3049/9385), me gustaría comparar las diferentes motivaciones que tienen los que participan con cierto ritmo en nuestro Meta.

Answer (score 3):

Porque hay veces en que nos permite cambiar cosas:

- [Do we want a different favicon for Spanish Language?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3051/1674)

Porque hay veces que nos permite definir líneas de actuación de una forma pausada, auditable y ordenada:

- [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674)

Porque permite un ambiente más distendido que el sitio principal, donde poder divagar un poco e ir animándose a proponer cosas

- Lo del favicon comenzó con una idea lanzada al aire por Charlie en https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2500/1674
- [¡Hagamos un póster para anunciarnos! / Let's have an Ad to promote the site!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2578/1674)

Porque nos permite ir conociéndonos mejor:

- [¿Quiénes somos?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2586/1674)

Porque nos permite sistematizar la ayuda a través de comentarios, sirviendo Meta de fuente de conocimiento:

- [Lista de comentarios útiles para el sitio](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2622/1674)

Porque nos permite establecer pautas de actuación futuras y auditables:

- [¡Ordenemos las etiquetas!](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2495/1674)

Porque nos permite destacar preguntas especialmente importantes:

- [¿Qué preguntas canónicas tenemos? What are the canonical answers we've discovered over the years?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2505/1674)
- [Nominaciones a la mejor respuesta / Best answer nominations (2018 Q1)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2883/1674)

Porque nos permite coger perspectiva sobre el sitio y debatir sobre él tranquilamente:

- [Retrospectiva de 2017 en Spanish.se // Spanish.se 2017 Retrospective](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2765/1674)

Comment: Y no te olvides de [cómo empezó el Translation-Golf](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2591/12637) y se definieron sus normas. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Porque me gusta ayudar a la gente, y porque me gusta colaborar en mejorar las cosas.

Y, en el caso específico de Spanish.SE, además de por lo anterior, lo hago también porque lo veo como un proyecto a medias y me gustaría verlo completado: graduado, con su tema propio, con ratios de participación acordes con los ratios de visitas, con sus ciclos de elecciones, con más usuarios activos, con eventos y *giveaways*...
Me gusta ayudar a crear cosas. Me gusta esa sensación de ver algo completo, que la gente usa y le gusta, y pensar que en parte es gracias a mí.
De momento hemos conseguido un favicon casi casi de diseño propio :) ¡Poco a poco!

PD: Bueno, y en ocasiones también por [esto](https://m.xkcd.com/386/), no nos vamos a engañar xD

Comment: Cómo definir el espíritu de Internet en una sola viñeta...

Answer (score 2):

When I was a child my mother impressed on me the importance of voting in elections because if I did not and they did something wrong I did not have a leg to stand on. In that spirit I contribute to the meta pages of the sites I am registered with and also to the overall meta.

In fact nothing has gone wrong but the principle was a good one for her to instill in me.

Comment: Great one! My mother also says it :)

Answer (score 1):

Porque nos permite ponernos de acuerdo sobre los límites del stack, como qué es *on-topic* y qué no, qué es una contribución de calidad, etc.

Todo esto podría hacerse directamente en las colas de revisión, con cada usuario aportando su propio voto sobre si una pregunta debe cerrarse o reabrirse, sobre si un post debe borrarse, etc. Esto es por supuesto válido, pero la mano izquierda no habla entonces con la derecha. Eso puede hacer que las reglas del sitio no sean consistentes y sean entonces más confusas para los nuevos usuarios (e incluso para los experimentados).

Por ejemplo, como aporto en [¿Qué quiere decir (y de dónde viene) “dejabugo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/29045/5481), cerrar esa pregunta porque al obtener la respuesta vemos que es una palabra inventada (no del español), nos llevaría a tener que cerrar otras similares como [What does “Bolobonchi” mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/10405/5481) por coherencia, y otras similares que seguramente no hemos detectado.

No usar meta para discutir estas cuestiones nos priva de la capacidad de compartir y confrontar opiniones y ponernos de acuerdo, que es algo que nos permite entender mejor qué queremos conseguir y cómo.

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo con lo que destacó fedorqui, y lo que mencióno @Charlie del aspecto diversión (como dice Dr Seuss, *Fun is good*).  Quería agregar:

Cuando un usuario se siente frustrado con algún aspecto del funcionamiento del sitio, puede buscar una solución en Meta sin perder puntos de reputación.

Por qué esto me parece importante: En la interacción en línea, a veces surgen frustraciones, que pueden afectar el estado de ánimo; si no hubiera Meta, un usuario ofendido o frustrado no tendría forma de tratar de resolver los conflictos interpersonales que surjan.  (En teoría existe la opción de usar "Contact Us", pero en la práctica, esta opción es de muy poco utilidad, porque StackExchange tarda varias semanas o incluso meses en responder, y sin diálogo, es difícil llegar a entenderse bien.)

Por otra parte, leí, no me acuerdo donde, que una Meta activa ayuda a los sitios Beta a avanzar hacia la graduación.